# Push() não funciona no VueJS?

Tags: array, vue.js

Preciso fazer um push() no `data` do VueJS e fazer com que ele acrescente mais um objeto no array de objetos que possui ali. Porém quando eu clico no botão que programei para que fizesse esse push() ele simplesmente não faz.

Segue código:

```
atualizar () {
    axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: '/server/inbox'
    }).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response.data)
      for (let e = 0; e < response.data.length; e++) {
        this.emails.push(
          {
            remetente: response.data.remetente,
            destinatario: response.data.destinatario,
            assunto: response.data.assunto,
            texto: response.data.texto
          },
          console.log('PUSH!')
        )
      }
    })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
      })
    console.log('Fim!')
  }
```

HTML:

```
<q-list no-border link inset-separator>
      <q-item v-for="email in emails" :key="email.id">
        <q-item-side icon="email"/>
        <q-item-main>
          <q-item-tile :label="emails.remetente">{{ email.remetente }}</q-item-tile>
          <q-item-tile :sublabel="emails.assunto">{{ email.assunto }}</q-item-tile>
        </q-item-main>
      </q-item>
    </q-list>
```

Está certo dessa maneira??

Esse é o método que criei para dar o push no array de objetos, e já fiz a conferência dos dados que estão vindo do servidor e está tudo certo, está retornando de maneira correta.

Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço...

Comment: Tens a certeza que `this` é o que pensas que é? Testa usar arrow functions assim: `}).then((response) => {`

Comment: Tentei colocar a arrow function, mas deu erro de sintaxe, qual seria o lugar correto para colocar ela?? Sinta-se a vontade para editar o código da pergunta, ou adicione uma resposta, ficarei feliz em aceitar a resposta se ela ajudar...

Comment: A melhor forma de agradecer é aceitando uma das respostas como solução e votando em todas que te ajudaram. :)

Comment: Foi exatamente o que eu fiz... Se desse eu aceitava as duas, mas só pode uma, então...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função passada ao .then da Promise do axios muda o contexto de execução dessa função. Tens de usar arrow functions, ou um alias [como Ian sugeriu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/231820/129).

Para usares arrow function é só mudar

```
}).then(function(response){
```

por

```
}).then((response) => {
```

Repara ainda que tens `this.emails.push({...}, console.log('PUSH!'))`. Esse `console.log` está no sitio errado.

Ou sejam, o código todo, corrigido:

```js
atualizar() {
  axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: '/server/inbox'
    }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data)
      for (let e = 0; e < response.data.length; e++) {
        this.emails.push({
          remetente: response.data.remetente,
          destinatario: response.data.destinatario,
          assunto: response.data.assunto,
          texto: response.data.texto
        });
        console.log('PUSH!', e);
      }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err)
    })
  console.log('Fim!')
}
```

Comment: Coloquei esse código lá e ele retornou o que vem do servidor no console do navegador, porém continua não gerando a atualização na tela, vou adicionar o HTML na pergunta e você pode me dizer o que está errado

Comment: @LeonardoEbert coloca um pedaço dessa resposta para podermos fazer um exemplo a funcionar.

Comment: @LeonardoEbert acredito que seu problema está no escopo do `this`, dê uma olhada com calma na minha resposta.

Comment: {remetente: "Leonardo -  <leonardo@email.com.br>", destinatario: "leonardo@gmail.com", assunto: "teste2", texto: "Teste2" }
assunto: "teste2"
destinatario: "leonardo@gmail.com"
remetente: "Leonardo "
texto: "Teste2" 

Apenas removi dados pessoais @Sergio

Essa é a response que vem do servidor e aparece no console do navegador

Comment: A response vem até o console, mas não entra no array de objetos nem atualiza a tela...

Comment: Sempre fiz dessa maneira e sempre funcionou, até hoje...

Comment: @LeonardoEbert é isto que procuras certo? https://jsfiddle.net/0rykp0o8/

Comment: É exatamente isso, porém não funciona no meu código, coloquei um ele aqui: https://codepen.io/LeonardoEbert/pen/GvBNZm

Obs: Estou usando o Quasar Framework

Comment: O que te dá `console.log(typeof response.data)`?

Comment: Retorna `object`

Comment: @LeonardoEbert ok, e o que dá `console.log(Array.isArray(response.data), response.data.length);`?

Comment: Esses últimos retorna `false` e `undefined`

Comment: @LeonardoEbert interessante, isso é inesperado. O que dá `console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));`?

Comment: Retorna uma String com a response que vem do servidor: {"remetente":"Leonardo", "destinatario":"leonardo@gmail.com", ...}

Comment: @LeonardoEbert então não tens uma array. Testa tirar o loop `for` e usar somente `this.emails.push(response.data);`

Comment: Até que enfim funcionou, muito obrigado Sérgio, muito obrigado mesmo...

Comment: @LeonardoEbert de nada :)

Comment: Depois de muita briga com o código funcionou : D... Muito obrigado mesmo...

Answer (score 2):

Nesse caso o `this` não está referenciando a $vm. Você pode fazer assim:

```
atualizar () {
  var self = this;

  axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: '/server/inbox'
  }).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data)
    for (let e = 0; e < response.data.length; e++) {
      self.emails.push(
      {
        remetente: response.data.remetente,
        destinatario: response.data.destinatario,
        assunto: response.data.assunto,
        texto: response.data.texto
      })
    }
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
  console.log('Fim!')
}
```

você pode melhorar um pouco seu código, assim:

```
atualizar () {
  var self = this;

  axios.get('/server/inbox')
    .then(({data}) => {
      for (let e = 0; e < data.length; e++) {
        self.emails.push({
          remetente: data.remetente,
          destinatario: data.destinatario,
          assunto: data.assunto,
          texto: data.texto
        })
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  console.log('Fim!')
}
```

Você pode entender mais sobre isso, [nessa série de vídeos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBInMy61plk&list=PLy5T05I_eQYNQs4Pta85XRSucm3IOHx2M).

Comment: Dá uma olhada com calma na minha sugestão.

Comment: Vou olhar, aliás, gostei da série de vídeos, muito obrigado pela recomendação...

Comment: Chegou a olhar o HTML?? Talvez o erro não está lá??

Comment: Não, não acredito ser no HTML. Você consegue dar um `console.log` na lista de emails no `then`?

Comment: Fiz um `console.log` no `self.emails` e retornou somente um array com os dois objetos estáticos que já tenho criado

Comment: Como você carrega esse array de emails inicialmente?

Comment: Tenho 2 objetos que usei apenas para testar, coloquei o código aqui: https://codepen.io/LeonardoEbert/pen/GvBNZm

Comment: Tenta dar um `console.log(self.emails)` logo abaixo desse `console.log(response.data)`

Comment: Dei um `console.log`, e ele só mostra os 2 objetos estáticos que tenho dentro do `emails[]`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64357/discussion-between-ian-rodrigues-and-leonardoebert).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Ian, agradeço imensamente, não acreditei quando vi que o problema era o `for`

Comment: @IanRodrigues você não pode adicionar solução na pergunta. Se já respondeu com a solução abaixo, isso é suficiente. Evite fazer esse tipo de edição.

Comment: @Articuno, tudo bem, eu estava apenas tentando melhorar o que ele escreveu. Ainda estou tentando entender a plataforma. ;)